# tasker: grace time on events

Tags: wi-fi, networking, tasker

I use tasker to act on state change on wireless services (WifI on, Bluetooth connected, ...).

There are cases where, for a very short time, the state of a service changes (no matter the reason: a thicker wall, repairing of BT, ...) and the exit actions are triggered.
This is particularly annoying when I rely on continuity (I have, for instance, Waze being killed when the connection to my car's BT is over - but the car sometimes requests a repairing out of the blue and Waze is killed -- which by the way never happens on a 120 km highway section but always right on the middle of complicated turns in a city :)).

What would be the best way to configure a "grace period"?

```
when an action is triggered (say, by BT disconnecting)
  wait for *n* seconds
    then if the state is still there (= BT is disconnected)
      go ahead with the actions to perform
    otherwise
      do nothing
```

I know that I can add the logic above to selected actions but this is cumbersome and prone to errors (a short cut may trigger an exit action, then immediately after an entry one, while my timer on the exit one is still running). It would b better if the "state" of a service was aware of the possibility of these short interruptions (and therefore manage correctly the exit and entry actions)

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Depends a lot of what your tasks are doing. A separate profile won't do (as it doesn't steer other running tasks). You could try starting your exit tasks with a *Tasker->Wait* for, say, 10..15s (whatever the maximum interruption usually is), and play with the collision settings (what to do if a condition is triggered while the profile is still active -- here the new "runner" could take over). I never tried that, so I cannot say whether that might work.

Comment: This is a very interesting idea. I will test this over the next few days and be back with feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Looking forward to your feedback with lots of interest! Please don't forget about it :)